# Determine the joint moment generating function $M_{V,W} (s_1, s_2)$ of V and W

Tags: random-variable, moments, moment-generating-function

So the initial question was:
Let X and Y be independent random variables with common moment generating function
$m_X(s) = m_Y (s) = e^{s^2/2}$.

a) Determine the moment generating function $M_V (s)$ of $V := X + Y$.

For this I ended up getting $M_V (s) = e^{s^2}$.

b) Determine the moment generating function $M_W (s)$ of $W := Y X$.

For this I ended up getting $M_W (s) = 1/\sqrt{1-s^2}$.

c) Determine the joint moment generating function $M_{V, W} (s_1, s_2)$ of V and W, i.e., please
find $E[e^{s_1 V}e^{s_2 W}]$.

And this is the one I am having trouble on, any hints to get started?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.